# Should multiple adjustedment correction be applied here?

Tags: t-test, bonferroni

I have a question. I'm analysing an article for an assignement.

In this study there are two groups (normal d-dimer vs elevated d-dimer). The study compaires the mean of the groups for multiple variables around 30. By performing independent samples t-test.

Should they also make an adjustment for multiple testing like bonferoni? This is not performed in the statistical analysis. And would bonferonni be the right choice?

Yumeng Yao, Jiatian Cao, Qingqing Wang et al. D-dimer as a biomarker for disease severity and mortality in COVID-19 patients: a case control study, 03 April 2020, PREPRINT (Version 1) available at Research Square [+https://doi.org/10.21203/rs.3.rs-20850/v1+]

[image]